# Java: Checking if image moved

Tags: java, image, image-processing, pixel, image-extraction

I want to look within a certain position in an image to see if the selected pixels have changed in color, how would I go about doing this? (Im trying to check for movement)

I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
public int[] rectanglePixels(BufferdImage img, Rectangle Range) {
  int[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
  int[] boxColors;  
    for(int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
      for(int x = 0; x < img.getWidth; x++) {
        boxColors = pixels[(x & Range.width) * Range.x + (y & Range.height) * Range.y * width]
      }
    }
  return boxColors; 
}
```

Maybe use that to extract the colors from the position? Not sure if im doing that right, but after that should I re-run this method, compare the two arrays for similarities? and if the number of similarities reach some threshold declare that the image has changed?

Comment: How are your images produced?

Answer (score 1):

One approach to detect movement is the analysis of pixel color variation considering the entire image or a subimage in distinct times (*n*, *n-1*, *n-2, ...)*. In this case you are considering a fixed camera. You might have two thresholds:

1. The threshold of color channel variation that defines that two pixels are distinct.
2. The threshold of distinct pixels between the images to consider there is movement. In other words: two images of the same scene at time *n* and *n-1* have just 10 distinct pixels. It is a real movement or just noise?

Below an example showing how to counter the distict pixels in an image, given a color channel threshold.

```
for(int y=0; y<imageA.getHeight(); y++){
        for(int x=0; x<imageA.getWidth(); x++){

            redA = imageA.getIntComponent0(x, y);
            greenA = imageA.getIntComponent1(x, y);
            blueA = imageA.getIntComponent2(x, y);

            redB = imageB.getIntComponent0(x, y);
            greenB = imageB.getIntComponent1(x, y);
            blueB = imageB.getIntComponent2(x, y);

            if
            (
                Math.abs(redA-redB)> colorThreshold ||
                Math.abs(greenA-greenB)> colorThreshold||
                Math.abs(blueA-blueB)> colorThreshold
            )
            {
                distinctPixels++;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, there are [Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/) plug-ins to do so. Check this [source code example](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/examples/motionRegions.html). It detects and display regions containing "movements", as shown in the image below.

[image]

There are more sophisticated approaches that determine/subtract background for this purpose or deal with camera movements. I guess you should start from the simplest scenario and then go to more complex ones.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [BufferedImage.getRGB(startX, startY, w, h, rgbArray, offset, scansize)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) unless you really want to play around with the loops and extra arrays.

Comment: Didn't even know that existed! Does that return a cropped image in the form of an RGB array?

Comment: Yup, and it's a oneliner.

Comment: And you could add some additional logic after taking 2 snapshots, if you want to see the direction of movement.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two values through a threshold would serve as good indicator. Perhaps, you could calculate averages for each array to determine color and compare the two? If you do not want a threshold value just use .hashCode();